# Not getting location updates in activity

Tags: android, location

I am trying the code from developer.android.com [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) and I am unable to receive location updates. It just shows the location once and then stops. Here is my code. Please tell me what am I doing wrong

```
public class TestClass extends FragmentActivity implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

LocationClient mLocationClient;
Location mLocation;
boolean mUpdatesRequested;
// Milliseconds per second
private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
// Update frequency in seconds
public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;
// Update frequency in milliseconds
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// The fastest update frequency, in seconds
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
// A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// Define an object that holds accuracy and frequency parameters
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
Editor mEditor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_main);
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    // Open the shared preferences
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Get a SharedPreferences editor
    mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
     * callbacks.
     */
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    // Start with updates turned off
    mUpdatesRequested = false;

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Save the current setting for updates
    mEditor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", mUpdatesRequested);
    mEditor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    /*
     * Get any previous setting for location updates Gets "false" if an
     * error occurs
     */
    super.onResume();
    if (mPrefs.contains("KEY_UPDATES_ON")) {
        mUpdatesRequested = mPrefs.getBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);

        // Otherwise, turn off location updates
    } else {
        mEditor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);
        mEditor.commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        /*
         * Remove location updates for a listener. The current Activity is
         * the listener, so the argument is "this".
         */
        removeLocationUpdates(this);
    }
    /*
     * After disconnect() is called, the client is considered "dead".
     */
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

private void removeLocationUpdates(TestClass testClass) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    mLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "One " + mLocation + " Two",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Report to the UI that the location was updated
    String msg = "Updated Location: "
            + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + ","
            + Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // If already requested, start periodic updates
    if (mUpdatesRequested) {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a fast proposal:

> public LocationRequest setInterval (long millis)
>
> This interval is inexact. You may not receive updates at all (if no location sources are available), or you may receive them slower than requested.

Are you sure you are getting location data?

**UPD**

Field `mUpdatesRequested` is never set as true in this code. Clean the prefs (clean app data in settings) and set `mUpdatesRequested = true;` in `onCreate` and comment the code in `onResume` method because it always sets `mUpdatesRequested` as false. Or save prefs with true value beforehand.

Comment: I get it first time the activity is loaded.

Comment: so what should I change it to?

Comment: First time location manager delivers you last known location data and after that you do not receive any updates because you don't have any location sources available. Thats my proposal. Do you have gps available, for instance?

Comment: Oh! It seems to me that `mUpdatesRequested` is never set as true:)

Comment: I made it true while declaring it. Still not working

Comment: You should also remove code from onresume method - it always sets mUpdatesRequested to false if you didn't set it before activity launch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50620/discussion-between-vyprnoch-and-bluebyte)